# When did a test first fail?

Tags: testing, tfs

Using TFS, is there any way to find out when a test first failed?

I am new to TFS and to the project, where we have a couple of unit tests failing since a while back, but we do not know what change that was committed when they first broke. When committing to TFS, the tests are run automatically. So is there any way TFS can save that info in a log, so we can take a close look at exactly what happened the the code when the tests started to fail?

Alternatively, suggestions for other tools that can do this are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are aware, ultimately, it doesn't matter when a unit test first failed. What's important is (1) you fix the cause of the broken tests, (2) the team gets notified immediately when any test breaks. That said, I agree that knowing what changed can help find the cause.

I'm a bit rusty with TFS (and don't have one in front of me), but:

Test results are stored in tbl_TestResult in the collection database.

Test results' attachments are stored in tbl_Attachment also in the collection database.

Do you have the TFS cube setup?

Might be of use to you: [Test steps and results in TFS 2010](http://almsweden.com/2011/01/test-steps-and-results-in-tfs-2010/)

Comment: Thank you, I will look in to those tables. No, I never heard of the TFS CUBE before. Is it meant for better navigation through things like this in the underlying db? In TeamCity, there is a report for every build, including the changes.

Comment: The Cube is a really useful reporting tool. You can show various time frames and a myriad of metrics.